# Can I limit the size of a C++14 Vector?

Tags: c++, c++14

As the tile says, is there anyway that I can declare a vector in C++ 14 and limit the max number of entries it can hold?

Comment: I guess you could do this with a custom allocator (although I strongly advise against it). What would you want to happen when you try to add stuff to your "bounded vector" beyond capacity? An exception? You could write a wrapper class that checks the length each time...

Comment: An excpetion, just as when I push one more than the default max size

Comment: Pushing one more than the default max size doesn't mean anything. `max_size()` gives you an estimate of how many elements a vector can hold, but that estimate has no consequences. There is no requirement to throw an exception if that estimate is exceeded. And there is no guarantee that you can in fact create a vector with that many elements. Best advice: pretend that `max_size()` doesn't exist.

Comment: A vector that throws an exception after it reaches a (smallish) maximum size is likely to be an unpleasant surprise for other programmers who are expecting a vector's to provide its usual behavior -- you might consider instead making the vector into a private member variable of another class, and providing a different API via the methods of that class.

Comment: @PeteBecker I imagine that there must be an upper limit to the number of elements, perhaps the size of a unit64? Or? Given infinite RAM will C++ never report "a push too far"? The Vector structure presumably has to store its current number of elements - else it would have to count them too frequently to be efficient. If so, then whatever happens when that is exceeded is what I would expect when my theoretical size limit were exceeded. But, nvm, this is just a thought experiment, as it can't be easily done. I will not be pursuing this. Thanks for the feedback, though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution would be to create your own *Allocator*. `std::allocator` is stateless, but yours could implement the `max_size()` member function which should return the value of a member variable that carries the max number of elements.

An example that will work from C++11 up until at least C++20:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct limited_allocator : public std::allocator<T> {
    using value_type = typename std::allocator<T>::value_type;
    using size_type = typename std::allocator<T>::size_type;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;

    using is_always_equal = std::false_type; // not needed since C++23

#if __cplusplus < 201703L
    using pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::const_pointer;
    using reference = typename std::allocator<T>::reference;
    using const_reference = typename std::allocator<T>::const_reference;

    template<class U> struct rebind {
        typedef limited_allocator<U> other;
    };
#endif
    
    // No default constructor - it needs a limit:
    constexpr limited_allocator(size_type max_elements) noexcept :
        m_max_elements(max_elements) {}

    constexpr limited_allocator( const limited_allocator& other ) noexcept = default;

    template< class U >
    constexpr limited_allocator( const limited_allocator<U>& other ) noexcept :
        m_max_elements(other.m_max_elements) {}

    // Implementing this is what enforces the limit:
    size_type max_size() const noexcept { return m_max_elements; }

private:
    size_type m_max_elements;
};
```

Since this allocator isn't stateless, you'd better implement the non-member comparison functions too:

```cpp
template< class T1, class T2 >
constexpr bool operator==(const limited_allocator<T1>& lhs,
                          const limited_allocator<T2>& rhs ) noexcept {
    return &lhs == &rhs;
}

template< class T1, class T2 >
constexpr bool operator!=(const limited_allocator<T1>& lhs,
                          const limited_allocator<T2>& rhs ) noexcept {
    return &lhs != &rhs;
}
```

A usage example, in which the `vector` is allowed to keep `1` element only:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int, limited_allocator<int>> vec(limited_allocator<int>(1));
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    try {
        vec.push_back(1);   // one element
        vec.pop_back();     // zero again
        vec.push_back(2);   // one again
        vec.push_back(3);   // here it'll throw
    }
    catch(const std::length_error& ex) {
        std::cout << "length_error: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }    
    catch(const std::bad_array_new_length& ex) {
        std::cout << "bad_array_new_length: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::bad_alloc& ex) {
        std::cout << "bad_alloc: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
length_error: vector::_M_realloc_insert
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qq8aTf8jc)

Comment: Isn't max_size deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++20?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, in `std::allocator` but `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::max_size` calls it if it's implemented in `Alloc`

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's a nice code example, +1. (Though I still wonder what will happen in C++23 where `max_size` is to be removed. Care to comment fuether? The above comment was not clear to me.) I'd like to know though: Would you use it in practice? (Can you imagine a use-case? I'm struggling to come up with one and wonder what OP's use-case is)

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Thanks! It'll likely work in C++23 too. Even though `std::allocator<T>::max_size` was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20. [`std::allocator_traits<Alloc>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) which _"provides the standardized way to access various properties of Allocators"_ still has a [`max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/max_size). That `max_size` will call `Alloc::max_size` **if it exists** and fall back to the default, `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(value_type)`, if `Alloc::max_size` doesn't exist.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Use-cases: The allocator as implemented above could be used in testing where you'd put different constraints on different allocating classes. One could also easily modify it to take the max size as a template parameter instead (and make `is_always_equal` a `std::true_type` and modify the comparison functions accordingly) to make it more similar to the standard allocator. If your program is to run in a constrained environment you could also implement the `allocate`/`deallocate` methods to fetch memory from a fixed size area to put an upper limit on heap allocations etc.